# Existe alguma política para apelidos e fotos no site?

Tags: debate

Existe alguma política no site para permitir/não permitir que usuários usem apelidos e fotos de terroristas/psicopatas/serial killers/grupos extremistas/terroristas em seus perfis? pergunto isso porque participo de outros fóruns (moeda virtual, download a baixo custo) e cbox onde os moderadores estão fazendo uma faxina com perfis com estas características.

Comment: Aqui tem uma dica para a resposta: http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy mas não consigo responder agora.

Comment: Na dúvida, sinalize. Eu acredito que esse tipo de perfil precise sim de intervenção dos moderadores e/ou gerentes de comunidade.

Comment: @rray sabias que há pessoas no mundo com esse nome?

Comment: Bem, conheço um usuário desta comunidade que usa a foto de um terrorista psicopata serial killer muito perigoso chamado Cell. Este mesmo usuário antigamente usava a foto de um outro terrorista muito perigoso, chamado Majin Boo. Dá-lhe kamehameha!

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu tenho um amigo com esse nome. Felizmente ele é progressista, do bem e não é programador.

Comment: @VictorStafusa não conheço este usuário. Medidas dever ser tomadas pelos moderados, não podemos deixar pessoas assim a solta.

Comment: @Ricardo. Pois é, que coisa! Aliás, você viu o Freeza por aí? É outro terrorista muito perigoso! :D kkkkkk

Comment: chamando @Techies para alterar o nome e a imagem, não permitindo terroristas no site haha

Comment: Esse é um assunto que não ouso fazer piadas.
@Ricardo, fiquei curioso sobre os fóruns, poderia me passar o link?